# Changing black pixels to be transparent in matlab

Tags: matlab, background, pixel, transparent

First, I'm new to matlab, so thanks in advance for any help.

I have a .png image that I have overlayed onto another image.  How can I make only the black pixels on the .png image transparent?  I have looked around and no one seems to specifically address this question clearly.  I was trying to use either the 'BackgroundColor' function or alphadata.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [EXPORT_FIG](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) submission from the File Exchange.

I believe it supports background color transparency for PNG files.